# Why do I get "Syntaxwarning Object not callable; perhaps maybe missing a comma"?

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I am trying to write a program that monitors a shoe price from a website, but I get an error that says:

> ```
> syntaxwarning object not callable;perhaps you missed a comma?
> ```

Here is the code to my program:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class snkrsBot:

def __init__(self, sneaker_url):
    self.sneaker_url = sneaker_url
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')

def get_price(self):    
    self.driver.get(self.sneaker_url)
    price = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-test="product-price"]')
    return int(price.get_attribute('innerHTML').strip('£'))

def main():
    url = 'https://www.nike.com/gb/t/air-max-95-essential-shoe-7hwG30/AT9865-001'
    bot = snkrsBot(url) 
 last_price = None
    while True:
        price = bot.get_price()
        if last_price:
            if price < last_price:
                print('Price dropped:'(last_price - price))
            elif price > last_price:
                print('Price rose:'(price - last_price))
            else:
                print('Price is the same'(price))    
        last_price = price
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: This question could use some cleanup. You say "syntaxwarning"... was it a "SyntaxError"? Your indentation isn't right so we can't just copy / paste to test. And you didn't post the actual traceback message which includes valuable information such as the line with the error. Please fix these problems so that we have a good quality question to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Your `print`s are all wrong; the error is telling you you tried to call a `str` literal as if it were a function with arguments. Change to:

```
        if price < last_price:
            print('Price dropped:', last_price - price)
        elif price > last_price:
            print('Price rose:', price - last_price)
        else:
            print('Price is the same', price)
```

All I did was add three commas, and remove pointless parentheses around the values to print.